# Php how to use multi tables in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

So I have two tables in my phpmyadmin like

`tabel1 and tabel2`

in both tables, i want to select id = 2

so I have tried

`mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabel1, table2
WHERE id=2');`

but not working plz give me some suggestions

Comment: it seems TYPO mistake as `tabel1` need to be `table1`

Comment: I've already written that in my answer below

Comment: You should show us table structure here, along with the output you want.  A `UNION` might be appropriate, but that would depend on several things.

Comment: What is the structure of both tables? Do they contain the same columns or different ones? What does "not working" mean? Is there an error message that comes up?

Comment: use inner join with where clause

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to accomplish what you want.

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: This would only work if the two tables had the same number, types, and order of columns, which may not be the case.

Comment: No problem. Note however, that its not the most performant way to handle large sets of data. If you find yourself in a position where you need to use a UNION statement, you should most likely take a look at your datamodel to see if some improvements are required.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact requirements, the query might be as easy as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1, table2
  WHERE table1.id=2 AND table2.id=2
```

You are implicitly joining your tables for the condition of `table1.id` and `table2.id` being equal 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join and also read [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
 mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabel1 as t1
 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
 WHERE t1.id=2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo there. You said you have `table1`and `table2`

Then your SQL statement should be

`mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE id=2');`

instead of

`mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabel1, table2 WHERE id=2');`

what was in your question.

Comment: TYPO need to be commented not add an answer.BTW NOT A DOWN-VOTER

Comment: I commented it at first, but SO told me "Do not answer questions in comments" and since this could be the solution to his problem, i considered it a real answer and I re-posted it as an answer. And btw thanks that you didn't down-vote :)